# Assign a multiline output from grep into a variable

Tags: bash, variables, grep, double-quotes

I have a data file, named `words`, which is made of rows and 3 columns. First column is a german word, second is its translation and third some metadata like verb, noun, etc...

```
$ cat words
offen open verb
Fenster window noun
Regd shelf noun
```

To grab all the nouns I could use `grep`,

```
$ cat words | grep noun
Fenster window noun
Regd shelf noun
```

I like that output because each record in its own row. The problem comes when
I am trying to **store that output in a variable**,

```
$ nouns=$(cat words | grep noun)
```

**The output now is one line** where those two records merged into one,

```
$ echo $nouns
Fenster window noun Regd shelf noun
```

How can I assign a multiline output from `grep` into a variable?

Comment: The problem is how you __print__ the variable. Assignment is fine.

Comment: How should I print it @KamilCuk?

Comment: If you don't want the new lines to be printed then there's the `-n` option for `echo`. So shouldn't by default print the new lines? I mean I could use `printf` but I would still want to know the reason.

Comment: @KamilCuk: did you reopen the Q? - I was trying to find the _exact_ dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/q/29378566/5291015. Could you close it ?

Comment: The variable needs to be enclosed in double quotes, `echo "$nouns"` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51665500/9164071)